# can we manually test multithreaded and multitasking system?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing

For example : Multilingual sites can not be checked manually ,because it will take more time and slows down process, so we test them by automated tool.

Is it also not possible to test multi-threaded and multitasking systems manually ?

if no then why?

Comment: you can check manually but that will be long time taking task so best to prefer automation testing for that type of system.

Comment: but to say that multithreaded and multitasking system can not be checked manually will be wrong , isn't it ?

Comment: It's only partially true. Some aspects you can verify for one user and you can start from doing it manually. However, you will then would like to verify whether concurrent users are not impacting each other. You can define scenarios with two users and perform them manually, e.g., when trying to open two web browser windows and updating same field concurrently. However, you should also test system for more users and that's usually easier when automated.

Comment: Yes.. but when it comes to multi-threading and multitasking there will be limitation of manual testing. you can verify manually for 2/3/5 users but what if users are 1000+. so it is depends on scenarios and requirements.

Comment: and can we check multilingual sites manually ?

Comment: @TehreemFatima - Yes ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

What is your application ? how loaded do you expect it to be ? what are the risks involved ? can you and the stakeholders tolerate some bugs?

You can manually test something, even on large scale, using crowd sourcing services, or even by testing in production an alpha version by selected users. If the expected load is not high than you can even do it using a few of you coworkers.

Comment: Some concurrency scenarios you can even test yourself, opening two browser windows in parallel.

Comment: and by reading the code you might get clues as to where to focus your efforts

Answer (score 0):

Majority of modern applications are multithreaded. For instance any mobile application "hello world" level has at least 2 threads: GUI and the thread where main logic is being executed.

The absolute majority of test scenarios can be tested manually and automation should be considered and implemented when investment into automation will provide a benefit, for instance if you have 100 tests and plan to execute them 100 times in upcoming year, it's better to have them automated.

When it comes to performance testing, the main goal is to check how will your application behave under anticipated load. You can make some assumptions by using a [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) check application/database logs to see any long-running operations or queries, etc.

However some certain scenarios cannot be tested manually especially edge cases, for instance how your application behaves under prolonged load, what is number of concurrent users when errors start occurring and what kind of errors are they, does the system recover after overwhelming load and if yes how fast, etc. See [Why ‘Normal’ Load Testing Isn’t Enough](https://blazemeter.com/blog/why-%E2%80%98normal%E2%80%99-load-testing-isn%E2%80%99t-enough) article for more detailed explanation.